# JQGrid for PHP Replacing link text with icons

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I am using JQGrid for PHP.

See homepage [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=617)

I have added Edit and Delete to a column like this:

```
$g->set_actions(array(  
    "add"=>false, // allow/disallow add
    "edit"=>true, // allow/disallow edit
    "delete"=>true, // allow/disallow delete
    "rowactions"=>true, // show/hide row wise edit/del/save option
    "autofilter" => true, // show/hide autofilter for search
) 
);
```

It works well and does what it should but the Edit and Delete links are in text and I need to replace the text with images but don't know what/where I need to change this.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define your own formatter for the cells. See [this example.](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/functionality/custom_formatter/default.php)

[This page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/editing_data/datepicker/default.php) demonstrates using a predefined formatter, which would be another option, depending on your needs.